# Concatenating or cascading multiple pretrained keras models

Tags: keras, concatenation

I'm trying to build a concatenated or cascaded(actually don't even know if this is the correct definiton) set of models.
For the simplicity my base models are looking like below.

```
                              ----Input----
                                    |
                                  L1-1
                                    |  
                                  L1-2
                                    |
                                  Dense
                                    |
                                 Softmax
```

I got 7 of these models trained with cross-validation and trying to wrap up them in a cascade fashion such as:

```
            -----------------------Input---------------------
            |       |       |       |       |       |       |       
          L1-1    L1-2    L1-3    L1-4     L1-5   L1-6    L1-7
            |       |       |       |       |       |       |
          L2-1    L2-2    L2-3    L2-4     L2-5   L2-6    L2-7
            |       |       |       |       |       |       |
            |_______|_______|_______|_______|_______|_______|
            |                  Concatenated                 |
            |___________________Dense Layer_________________|
                                    |
                                 SoftMax
```

Each one of Dense Layers got `512` neurons so in the end Concatenated Dense Layer would have a total of`7*512=3584` neurons.

What I've done is:

- Trained all models and saved them in a list named as `models[]`.
- Popped the bottom Softmax Layer in all models.

Then I try to concatenate them but got the error:

```
Layer merge was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
```

What I'm gonna do after forming the cascade is freezing all the intermediate layers except `Concatenated Dense Layer` and tuning it up a little bit. But I'm stuck at as explained in all the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the functional API model for that. This kind of model works with tensors.

First you define a common input tensor:

```
inputTensor = Input(inputShape)
```

Then you call each model with this input to get the output tensors:

```
outputTensors = [m(inputTensor) for m in models]
```

Then you pass these tensors to the concatenate layer:

```
output = Concatenate()(outputTensors) 
output = Dense(...)(output)    
#you might want to use an Average layer instead of these two....

output = Activation('softmax')(output)
```

Finally, you define the complete model from start tensors to end tensors:

```
fullModel = Model(inputTensor,output)
```

Comment: `outputTensors = [m(inputTensor) for m in models]`
Dear sir, can you clarify what are we doing here exactly. What does that means calling models with an input tensor to get output tensors. Thanks.

Comment: A model behaves exactly like a layer. You "call" a layer passing a tensor. The result is an output tensor. So, suppose you have a model `m` and an input tensor `inputT`. The follwing calls the model: `output = m(inputT)`. In this line, you are "passing" the input tensor to the model, and the result of the call is the output tensor. ----- Now, in the line you mentioned, I created a list of output tensors, one for each of the models in your list `models`. That line means: for each model `m` in the list `models`, call this model `m` with `inputTensor`. This creates a list of output tensors.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for your precious time.